# Fire controller code when textbox date is changed in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirement to run some controller code whenever a user clicks out of a textbox which displays a date. My question is how can I run the controller code from the html textbox? I am a complete MVC noob and have been doing web forms up to now. For example my controller code is:

```
    [httppost]
    public ActionResult Availability(int id)
            { 
                //run code
            }
```

And I have a plain html textbox - I am not allowed to use html helpers only plain html. can I achieve this in javascript, jquery or use Ajax to do this? Textbox:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="To" name="DateTo" placeholder="To" required />
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use AJAX. Technically, this was all happening under the hood, implicitly, with your Web Forms code. MVC puts you in control, rather than the framework, is all.

So, you'll just have something like:

```
$('input[name=DateTo]').on('blur', function () {
    $.post('/url/to/action', { date: $(this).val() }, function (response) {
        // do something with response
    });
});
```

A couple of notes:

1. Your action takes an integer `id` param, but the value of your textbox is going to be a datetime. I'm not sure what you're doing exactly, but you'll need to figure out which it should actually be.
2. The code above was forced to select by attribute, since you have no id on the input. There's technically nothing wrong with that, per se, but it may not be what you want.
3. I'm not sure why you are "not allowed" to use HTML helpers here. Either that's a clueless requirement based on not understanding the framework, or you somehow think there's something you can't accomplish here with the HTML Helper. You can generate exactly the same bit of HTML via:

   ```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTo, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "To", required = true })
   ```

Comment: Yeah cant use html helpers as it generates the html for you, which we are trying to get away from. See the post('/url/to/action' part - what would I put in here if my controller is called Trainer and the action is called availability?

Comment: @wubblyjuggly: the default format is 
`{controller}/{action}/{parameters}`

Comment: @wubblyjuggly: No offense, but that's just silly. It's actually *better* to let the HTML be generated for you. By using something like `TextBoxFor`, Razor will ensure that the input gets the correct name in order to allow the modelbinder to bind it properly on post, and you're strongly-typed, so if the property name changes, you get an error, instead of things just silently no working because you forgot to change the name of the static input.

Comment: No offense taken, its just what ive been told to do

Comment: Part of your job as a developer is to protect the integrity of the code your author. If you're being required to something that is obviously ill-advised, you should feel free to speak up against that. Your employer should rely on your expertise; otherwise, why even have you there. If you don't feel like you can speak up, then, you should try to find a better employer.